# how to use between in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to filter the dates by month according to the domain.
Here's sample of data;

Domain - id : 1, 2

Domain - label : User1, User2

Fact_data - domain_id : 1, 2

Fact_data -  date : varies from '2016-01-01' to '2016-03-20'

This is the sql I have tried but it somehow have error.

```
SELECT d.label, COUNT(*) AS count, date_format(f.date, 'YYYY-MM') AS date
FROM domain d, fact_data f 
WHERE f.domain_id = d.id
AND f.date >= `2016-01-01` AND f.date <=`2016-01-31`
GROUP BY `domain_id`;
```

I want the result to be like;

```
|   domain  |   count   |   date   |
 ----------------------------------
|   User1   |     3     | 2016-01  |
|   User2   |     1     | 2016-01  |
|   User1   |     2     | 2016-02  |
|   User1   |     1     | 2016-03  |
|   User2   |     2     | 2015-03  |
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Use regular ticks `'` instead of backticks in the `AND f.date>=...` clauses. The backticks are for column/table/database names.

Comment: MySQL uses backticks to quote database, table and field names. I hope your real query doesn't look like you posted it here. Use either apostrophes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) to enclose the strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this will work:

```
SELECT d.label,
       COUNT(*) AS count,
       date_format(f.date, 'YYYY-MM') AS `date`
  FROM domain d JOIN fact_data f ON f.domain_id = d.id
 WHERE f.date >= '2016-01-01' AND f.date <='2016-01-31'
 GROUP BY d.label;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you should use single, ', or double, ", quotes with strings. Column names need backticks, `, if they conflict with a keyword, such as DATE or GROUP.

It sounds like you are trying to GROUP BY year and month, as well as domain. Am I correct? If so, your query should probably look something like this:

```
SELECT d.label, COUNT(*) AS count, date_format(f.date, 'YYYY-MM') AS `date`
FROM domain d, fact_data f 
WHERE f.domain_id = d.id
AND f.date >= '2016-01-01' AND f.date <='2016-01-31'
GROUP BY year(`date`), month(`date`), `domain_id`;
```

The title of your question indicates that you want to use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between). In that case, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT d.label, COUNT(*) AS count, date_format(f.date, 'YYYY-MM') AS `date`
FROM domain d, fact_data f 
WHERE f.domain_id = d.id
AND f.date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY year(`date`), month(`date`), `domain_id`;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to you all, the sql has run successfully!

However, I could not get the date

```
|   domain  |   count   |   date   |
 ----------------------------------
|   User1   |     3     | YYYY-MM  |
|   User2   |     1     | YYYY-MM  |
```

It returns 'YYYY-MM' not like the actual numbers (ex; 2016-01')
and I could not get it per month but just once for each domain only like above

Does anyone know what to add or edit?